Uninstall package with non-python files that weren't in distribution
I have a python app that has been deposited on pypi as described here.  The app runs an external software (blast+) and generates non-python files (various database and txt files, and an xml file that is fed back into the app).  Currently, my directory structure (when installed with pip into an environment called env) is:
lib/site-packages/app/file1.py...

after running this becomes:
lib/site-packages/app/file1.py...xml_file.xml, db_file.txt, db_file.pdb ...

When I pip uninstall app:
Found existing installation: app 1.1a0
Uninstalling app-1.1a0:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\username\appdata\local\anaconda3\envs\app_env\lib\site-packages\app-1.1a0.dist-info\*
    c:\users\username\appdata\local\anaconda3\envs\app_env\lib\site-packages\app\*
    c:\users\username\appdata\local\anaconda3\envs\app_env\scripts\app.exe
  Would not remove (might be manually added):
    c:\users\username\appdata\local\anaconda3\envs\app_env\lib\site-packages\app\all_proteins.txt
    c:\users\username\appdata\local\anaconda3\envs\app_env\lib\site-packages\app\all_proteins_db.pdb
    c:\users\username\appdata\local\anaconda3\envs\app_env\lib\site-packages\app\all_proteins_db.phr
    c:\users\username\appdata\local\anaconda3\envs\app_env\lib\site-packages\app\all_proteins_db.pin
    c:\users\username\appdata\local\anaconda3\envs\app_env\lib\site-packages\app\all_proteins_db.pot
    c:\users\username\appdata\local\anaconda3\envs\app_env\lib\site-packages\app\all_proteins_db.psq
    c:\users\username\appdata\local\anaconda3\envs\app_env\lib\site-packages\app\all_proteins_db.ptf
    c:\users\username\appdata\local\anaconda3\envs\app_env\lib\site-packages\app\all_proteins_db.pto
    c:\users\username\appdata\local\anaconda3\envs\app_env\lib\site-packages\app\results.xml

This isn't a massive deal I think, as the files are rewritten every run and if you install my app again it just regenerates the original folder.  But I'd rather not have unecessery files cluttering the place up and potentially scaring new users with the would not remove message.  Is there a way to specify that the package will generate the files and they should be deleted if the package is (perhaps in pyproject.toml)?
(If not, I could make the user specify a local dir to write the files too, rather than just setting that as the dir holding the python script associated with making the fies, which is what I do now - but I'd rather keep the user interface as simple as possible.)

The typical way to make sure that files are cleaned up by pip is to have the package contain empty placeholder files (with your desired filenames) in it's installation directory.
As needed, you then overwrite these files at runtime. When it comes time to uninstall, pip will remove files based on their name, not contents.

"…empty placeholder files…" The files will be overwritten on the next upgrade of the package.

@phd thanks for your reply - can I clarify why that would be a problem if they are empty and not interacting with the app before the app creates them itself?

@Markus Hirsimaki, I tried to upload my app with the files initially, and got an invalid distribution file error (although they were from a run, not empty files - I'll try with empty files and see if that works!)

@TimKirkwood The app creates them; they're overwritten on the next upgrade; the app … what? Fails or recreates them? If it recreates the problem is waste of time. If the problem is negligible — the rest is up to you.

@phd just to be sure i understand, you're saying that when i run pip install app -U, assuming my upgraded dist was made from a package directory that also contained the same empty files, then pip will over-write the empty files in app with a new collection of empty files, and this is inefficient timewise?

@TimKirkwood The very overwriting is hardly inefficient. Regenerating the files after every upgrade is surely inefficient. If that inefficiency doesn't bother you or if you cannot find a better way — no problem, go on.
